# ASP.NET MVC model binding with knockout.js

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I'd like to do some server-side model binding with form elements created with knockout.js, using some custom name attributes attached to each dynamically created DOM element. I know I can use AJAX but native HTML form posts would work out better for me right now. The js file looks like this:

```
function MyModel(){ 
   var self = this;
   var count = 0;
   var insertItem = function(eleToInsertAfter){
       var index = self.items.indexOf(eleToInsertAfter),
           notFound = -1;

       var item = {
           type: '',
           description: ''
       };

       if(index == notFound){
           self.items.push(item); // there are no items yet, just push this item
       } else {
           self.items.spilce(++index, 0, item); // insert after the 'eleToInsertAfter' index
       }
       ++count;
   }

   self.title = ko.observable('');
   self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

   self.insert = function(eleToInsertAfter){
       insertItem(eleToInsertAfter);
   }

   // insert the first item
   self.insert({
           type: '',
           description: ''
       });
}
   ko.applyBindings(new MyModel());
```

and the html markup looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/controller/action/">
     <input type="text" data-bind="value: title" />
     <ol data-bind="foreach: items">
          <li> 
               <!--I'd like to achieve this effect *name="[0].type"* and *name="[0].description"*, and so on -->
               <input type="text" data-bind="value: type, *attr: {name = '['+$index+'].type'}*" />
               <input type="text" data-bind="value: description, *attr: {name = '['+$index+'].description'}*" /><br />
               <button data-bind="click: $root.insert">Add Item</button>
          </li>
     </ol>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If I can achieve the above effect then the MVC controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult action(MyModelCS model){
    // do something

    return View();
}
```

and MyModelCS would look like this:

```
public class MyModelCS {
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string[] type { get; set; }
    public string[] description { get; set; }
}
```

I've implemented a similar version to this using just jQuery but now I'm required to do a similar version using Knockout.js instead.  I'm new to Knockout but I searched the documentation to find some help without any luck... please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$index` is [an observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) so you need to unwrap  with: `$index()`

```
<input type="text" 
   data-bind="value: type, attr: {name = '['+$index()+'].type'}" />
<input type="text"
   data-bind="value: description, attr: {name = '['+$index()+'].description'}" />
```